# Setup Dual Monitors for Intel4770-K

Tags: multiple-monitors

Im wondering what i might need to do in order to get "proper" dual monitors on a Win 8 64 bit machine with Intel 4770-K backed graphics... not discreet card yet. I was under the impression that it supported dual monitors as discreet devices?

If I plug monitors into the display port and the hdmi i get picture on both but it's a mirrored desktop and only one screen shows up in Screen Resolution settings of Windows 8 even after clicking detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose `Extend`.

If this doesn't work, it seems to be driver issue. Download and install Intel's latest drivers and try again.

Comment: Windows+P says I can't project. Am looking for driver updates now.

Comment: Cool, let me know when you have found them.

Comment: Ok so thats a bit embarrassing. It really was that easy, install the drivers. Prior to post, I installed everything (Intel) on MB disk and went to intel site to get latest drivers but the mistake I made was in only getting "processor" drivers. What I also needed to do and what ur answer prompted me to do was also go to the Intel "Graphics" download centre and get drivers for the 4600 as the "Processor" bundle of drivers apparently does not include these. All sorted now tho so many  thanks. Also for anyone else, the Intel Driver Update Utility failed for me so had to manually select drivers

Comment: Be advised that official-drivers.com is a known spam URL. You might want to change the link to point to Intel's official website.